# docker is not in the `container ls` or `ps` after docker run

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am running a docker container for a react application.

`frontend.Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:14 as builder

RUN mkdir -p /client

WORKDIR /client

COPY package.json /client

RUN npm install

COPY . /client

# copying the crt, key files for https
# COPY ../secret/website_com_au.key ../secret/website_com_au_chain.crt /client

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=builder /client/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

RUN chown nginx.nginx /usr/share/nginx/html/ -R
```

I am building the dockerfile without any error.

`sudo docker build -t nabil/website:webclient . -f frontend.Dockerfile`

There is also no error after `docker run`,

`sudo docker run -d --net=host nabil/website:webclient`

But when I run `docker ps` or `docker container ls`, I don't see the docker container there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker ps -a` to see all containers even container was dead.

Check `docker logs container_id` to see the reason why container was dead.

Comment: Yeah, `docker logs id` did the trick. There was a missing file.

Answer (score 0):

### Check the status of container created:

docker ps -a (OR)

docker container ls -a

### Check container logs for failing:

docker logs <container id/container name> (OR)

docker container logs <container id/container name>